# How to pass data in ionic2

Tags: angular, ionic2

I get data through http. I want to pass data to PlacesListPage. There are "id, name, category, ..." in my data. I want to use theese in PlacesListPage like this: {{xxx.id}}, {{xxx.name}}... Please help me...
xxx - for example)

```
import {Page, NavController, NavParams} from 'ionic-angular';
import {Http} from 'angular2/http';
import 'rxjs/Rx';
import {PlacesListPage} from '../places-list/places-list';
/*enter code here
  Generated class for the PlacesPage page.

  See http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/components/#navigation for more info on
  Ionic pages and navigation.
*/
@Page({
  templateUrl: 'build/pages/places/places.html',
})
export class PlacesPage {
  static get parameters() {
    return [[NavController], [Http], [NavParams]];
  }


  constructor(nav, http, navParams) {
    this.nav = nav;
    this.http = http.get('https://api.myjson.com/bins/2ud24').map(res => res.json()).subscribe(
        (data) => {
          this.data = data;
        });

}
```

Comment: What is `PlacesListPage`? Is it a service? Is it a custom element? Do you use it inside your `places.html`?

Comment: yes. it is custom page. I imported on top. 4-th line

Comment: Can you provide the code for it?

Comment: thanks. I solve my problem.

Comment: Would you like to provide the answer here for people how may encounter the same problem?

Answer (score 7):

You can use this approach as well:

```
let something = { test: 1 };
this.nav.push(existingPaymentModal, {something});
```

and than

```
constructor(private navParams: NavParams) {
        this.something = this.navParams.get("something");
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the NavController to pass data to the Page as you navigate to it:

```
this.nav.push(PlacesListPage, {
    xxx: this.data
});
```

Then use NavParams in your PlacesListPage to access the data:

```
constructor(navParams) {
    this.xxx = navParams.data.xxx;
}
```

http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/nav/NavParams/

Comment: but my data is an object. I can't pass object data to another page

Comment: yes. when I'm clicking to go another page with data. app doesn't work and show me error on console log

Comment: if you could provide the error in your original message i may be able to better help you

Comment: there are framework error on console log. but I know that it's not problem of framework. ((( I can't make that.