# Passing JSON Object with NavController

Tags: json, angular, ionic2

I want to pass a JSON Object to another Page in Ionic 2.
I tried like the following, but I get the exception

> Cannot read property 'user' of undefined.

Here 
[How to pass data in ionic2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36780195/how-to-pass-data-in-ionic2) someone asked the same, but it's without a clear, working answer.

```
 var jsonData =  JSON.parse(data);
 this.navCtrl.push(InfoPage, {jsonData});
```

**InfoPage**

```
export class InfoPage {

  jsonData = null;
  user = null;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private loadingCtrl: LoadingController, private navParams: NavParams) { 
    this.jsonData = this.navParams.get("jsonData");
  }

  ngOnInit() 
  {
     this.user = this.jsonData.user;
     console.log(this.user);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not entirely sure, but i would think something like this would work. On the other hand, I would think that using an intermediary service for this will work much better.

On the page you want to send data from:

```
let jsonData =  JSON.stringify(data);
this.navCtrl.push(InfoPage, {jsonData : jsonData});
```

On the page which retrieves the data:

```
export class InfoPage {

   jsonData = null;
   user = null;

   constructor(private navParams: NavParams) { 
      this.jsonData = JSON.parse(this.navParams.get("jsonData"));
   }

   ngOnInit() {
     this.user = this.jsonData.user;
     console.log(this.user);
  }
}
```

Let me again mention though, that it's better to store such data in a so called `PageService` which will be a singleton throughout your pages. You can use this to send data from one page to another. If you really want to stick with the parse/stringify, then I would expect my solution to work. Be aware that I didn't test it.

A second solution would be the use of a service, which perhaps you can use for other use-cases as well:

```
export class PageService {

   public pageData: any;

}
```

You should add this service to your root providers array. After that you can use it inside your pages like this:

*FirstPage* (sender)

```
export class FirstPage {

   private jsonData: any = {user: 'saskia'};

   constructor(private pageService: PageService) {}

   goToInfoPage(): void {
      this.pageService.pageData = this.jsonData;
      this.navCtrl.push(InfoPage);
   }

}
```

*InfoPage* (receiver)

```
export class InfoPage {

   user: string;

   constructor(private pageService: PageService) {}

   ionViewWillEnter() {
     this.user = this.pageService.pageData.user;  
     console.log(this.user); //saskia
   }
}
```

I'm using the `ionViewWillEnter` lifecycle hook, to assure that the data is obtained at the right time

Comment: `jsonData : jsonData`  ,are you sure about that?

Comment: Very positive. You can also make it `{"jsonData" : jsonData}` if that feels more intuitive :)

Comment: Sadly, does not work. Error: `Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1 at JSON.parse(...)`. Do you have any example for your PageService you mentioned above?

Comment: Sorry, mistake by me. Works fine, but im interested in the method you told me.